# How do i create a function to return a value in a javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this countdown timer

```
(function($){

    var options = {
        display_as_text     : false,
    remaining : 0,
        separator           : ':',
        significant_days    : 3,
    display_on_complete : null, // id of element to display when countdown is complete
    hide_on_complete : null // hide the timer once it hits zero
    };

    $.fn.countdown = function (config_options)
    {
        /*
         * Initialise
         *
         * Prepare data and trigger regular execution of code
         *
         * @param   container   Reference to DOM element where counter will be displayed
         */
        var initialise = function (container){

        }

        var update = function (seconds_remaining){          

        }
```

and i need to access the update and reset the time based on a value i send in but i dont know how to access it. Here is how i instantiate the plugin

```
$('#timer').countdown({remaining : 1000});
```

but how do i call the update to update the seconds...I tried to set it to a variable and call it but no go...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach (that I've seen) is to do things jQuery-UI style:

1. `$(selector).plugin({...})` binds the plugin and allows chaining in the usual fashion.
2. `$(selector).plugin('method')` calls `method` as an accessor.
3. `$(selector).plugin('method', arg)` calls `method` as a mutator with the specified `arg`.

So in your case, you'd want to add a bit of argument parsing logic to your plugin so that you could say things like `$(selector).countdown('update', 11)`.

You can use [`$.isPlainObject`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to figure out how the plugin was called and pull apart the variable length argument list:

```
$.fn.countdown = function(options) {
    if(!$.isPlainObject(options)) {
        var stdarg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        if(stdarg[0] == 'update' && stdarg.length > 1) {
            return this.each(function() {
                // Set up value using stdarg[1]
            });
        }
        // ...
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        // Bind as usual
    });
};
```

And a simple demo (reality would of course be cleaner and better organized): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DEVBD/

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure you want to retrieve the seconds remaining or call the `update` function inside the plugin. But either way It’s impossible to tell if this is included in the plugin without looking at the full source.

You can always add a custom API to the plugin if you manipulate it, using something like this inside the plugin scope:

```
$(this).data('countdown', {
    update: update
});
```

Then call it using:

```
$('#timer').data('countdown').update(12345);
```

The same idea would work for getting internal variables, such as seconds remaining, f.ex: (assuming that the internal variable is called `seconds_remaining`):

```
$(this).data('countdown', {
    getSecondsRemaining: function() {
        return seconds_remaining;
    }
});
```

And then:

```
$('#timer').data('countdown').getSecondsRemaining();
```